# Как делать запросы maven?

Tags: java, maven

Хочу сделать данный запрос "mvn -v", но выдает ошибку. Прикрепил скриншоты в доказательство того, что правильно прописаны пути, но всё равно что-то не так.

```
"mvn" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл ответ, нужно прописать в path вот такой путь:

```
C:\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin\
```

Вместо моего пути ваш до мавена, но в конце обязательно должен быть \bin\

Comment: что и указано в [доках по установке maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

Добавь maven в PATH. Как это сделать:
[https://www.codeflow.site/ru/article/maven__how-to-install-maven-in-windows#:~:text=%D0%92%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20PATH,__HOME%25%20%5C%20bin%C2%BB](https://www.codeflow.site/ru/article/maven__how-to-install-maven-in-windows#:%7E:text=%D0%92%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20PATH,__HOME%25%20%5C%20bin%C2%BB).

Так же попробуй выполнить в IDEA не через терминал.
[image: run maven from idea]

Comment: Process terminated. Только что попытался такой запрос выполнить. Делал mvn --version

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй создать новый Intellij проект, выбрав maven. Если его нет, среда должна его скачать.

[image: create maven idea project]

Comment: Не помогло. Я и так скачал maven в архиве и распаковал на диске C. Снова пытался сделать запрос - ничего.

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться gradle, он короче и удобнее.

Comment: Мне именно maven нужен, в этом дело

Comment: Попробуйте удалить maven и установить с помощью IDEA.